# React - call parent method in child component after passing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-modal

I am trying to create a modal component in which i pass the content of the given modal as a child.

```
< GGModal buttonLabel="Login" content={
    <LoginScreen
        setToken={setToken}
        token={token}
        setEmail={setEmail}
        email={email}
     />} />
```

and then in GGModal i display the content like this:

```
           <Modal
                isOpen={modalIsOpen}
                onRequestClose={closeModal}
                style={{
                    overlay: { zIndex: 2 },
                }}
            >
                {content}
            </Modal>
```

I would like to call a method defined in GGModal (closeModal) from any given content i pass to it. However I don't know how to pass props to the {content}

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clone the children in order to do it.

```
export default GGModal = ({buttonLabel, children}) => {
      const parentFunction => 'parent function';
       <Modal
            isOpen={modalIsOpen}
            onRequestClose={closeModal}
            style={{
                overlay: { zIndex: 2 },
            }}
        >
            {React.cloneElement(children, { parentFuntion })}
        </Modal>
 }


<GGModal buttonLabel='Login' /> <LoginScreen
        setToken={setToken}
        token={token}
        setEmail={setEmail}
        email={email}
     /> </GGModal>
```

Comment: {React.cloneElement(children, { parentFuntion })} 
did the trick! is there any drawback from cloning the element?
Marked as solution

Answer (score 0):

use **children** prop instead of defining your custom prop. React is configured to take **children** prop as any jsx element passed as child. Make sure to provide children as last prop in the arguments.

```
export default function GGModal({buttonLabel, children}){
       <Modal
            isOpen={modalIsOpen}
            onRequestClose={closeModal}
            style={{
                overlay: { zIndex: 2 },
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </Modal>
 }
```